# CNTK Crashes Python when imported : Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cntk

I have installed CNTK CPU only version module using pip

```
pip3 install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

When i imported in spyder IDE, it was working fine. But when i tried to install other modules likes pandas, numpy using pip it crashes Python and says stopped working.

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>pip3 install pandas
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\cntk\io\__init__.py", line 1
3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk'
```

It says There is no module names CNTK and crashes Python. I am unable to open Python IDE after this.

Any idea why this happens? I uninstalled and installed for nearly 4 times. It still a problem.

[image: img]

Comment: Maybe , you have install `cntk` on `Python2`

Comment: No i installed the correct version of Python3.6. https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl  64bit, Python3.6 wheel

Comment: Which version do you running on your console?

Comment: You'd better check which version of `pip` is by run `which pip` on your command line (if you got Unix-Like System)

Comment: Hi i have installed using Pip3 and it was working fine for a moment. But crashes Python. I am unable to open it after this.